Help with solving an ODE involving nested square roots
I'm struggling with finding a closed-form solution for the following non-linear ODE:
$$ \sqrt{\alpha+\sqrt{1-\beta^2\left(f'(x)\right)^2}} = f(x) $$
where $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $ are real coefficients, and $ f(x) $ is a differentiable real-valued function. I'm interested in finding a solution for $ x $ in terms of known functions or expressions, if possible.
I've attempted various approaches, including isolating $ x $ by squaring both sides and attempting to rearrange terms, but so far, I haven't been successful in finding a closed-form solution. The presence of the function $ f(x) $ inside the square root seems to complicate the problem significantly. I also tried with $f=\frac{1}{\beta}\cos \phi$ but I ended with
$$\sqrt{\alpha+\left|\cos(\phi) \frac{d\phi}{dx}\right|} = \frac{1}{\beta} \cos(\phi)$$
After this substitution, it appears that we have reached a dead end.
Does anyone have insights, suggestions, or alternative methods that could be applied to solve or at least approach this equation? Additionally, if there are any relevant mathematical techniques or theorems that I might be overlooking, please feel free to point them out.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Wolfram generates a closed-form solution for $\alpha=\beta=1$. Maybe that can suggest some substitutions: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sqrt%281%2Bsqrt%281-y%27%5E2%29%29+%3D+y%28x%29

Wolfram also solve the general equation upon taking squares on both sides (but perhaps there's a reason you don't want to or cannot do that)

Solve the ODE for the inverse function $x(f)$.

Continuing with your substitution:
$$\sqrt{\alpha+\left|\cos(\phi)\frac{d\phi}{dx}\right|}=\frac{1}{\beta}\cos(\phi)$$
Rearranging:
$$\frac{\cos(\phi)}{\cos^2(\phi)-\alpha\beta^2}d\phi = \pm\frac{1}{\beta^2}dx$$
Integrating both sides:
$$\int{\frac{\cos(\phi)}{\cos^2(\phi)-\alpha\beta^2}d\phi} = \pm\frac{x}{\beta^2} +c$$
Substituting $u = \sin(\phi) ; du = \cos(\phi)d\phi$
$$\int{\frac{du}{1-u^2-\alpha\beta^2}} = \pm\frac{x}{\beta^2} +c$$
Now depending on the sign of $1-\alpha\beta^2$, you can use partial fractions or trigonometric substitution for the integral on L.H.S.
